# Enforce exact 4-spaces indentation with Checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

How do I make chekstyle check that every indentation have four spaces, not five, not eigth.

```java
// good
var foo = baz()
    .bar()
    .foo();
```

```java
// bad
var foo = baz()
        .bar()
        .foo();
```

Comment: Add a rule that every line match `^( {4})*(\S.*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Checkstyle's indentation check only ensures that your line wrapping indentation is *at least* 4. You can configure IndentationCheck to enforce exactly four spaces using the `forceStrictCondition` property:

```
<module name="Indentation">
  <property name="forceStrictCondition" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Read more at [Checkstyle Indentation](https://checkstyle.org/checks/misc/indentation.html).